# Аналог типа Variant

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, сериализация

Портирую на Java один протокол. Суть протокола: сообщения состоят из двух частей - структура данных и сами данные. Типы данных описываются в структуре и могут быть

- Boolean
- Int8
- Int16
- Int32
- Int64
- Double
- DateTime
- String

И массивы из этих данных. Целые типы могут быть знаковыми и беззнаковыми

В оригинальной реализации для работы с этими данными был использован тип `Variant`, а при сериализации/десереализации значений сериализатор смотрел на тип в структуре и кастовал Variant к соответствующему примитивному типу.

На Java я реализовал класс `Variant`, который внутри хранит свой тип и некоторое значение типа `Object`, а при обращении к этому классу из этого значения добывается нужное значение. Т.е. получился такой расширенный наследник `Number` с реализованным двусторонним кастом и поддержкой массивов.

Собственно вопрос, а не занимаюсь ли я ерундой и нет ли какого-то более простого способа реализации? Скажем, как-то дженерики сюда прикрутить или еще что-нибудь?